# getting duplicate data while fetch messages list firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

Hello i am creating Chat App Using Swift And Firebase i am fetching messages and populating in tableview but when i send new message then tableview dislplaying multiple entry i am useing below code for fetching messages

```
func fetchAllMessage(){
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let fetchMsgGroup = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages_group_iOS").child(uid).child(self.chatID)
        fetchMsgGroup.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists(){
                if let dictonary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    self.groupMessageData.removeAll()
                    if let userMessages = dictonary["userMessages"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        for (key, _) in userMessages{
                            let messagesFrtchRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages_iOS").child(key)
                            messagesFrtchRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot1) in
                                if snapshot1.exists(){
                                    if let dict = snapshot1.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                                        let fromId = dict["fromId"] as! String
                                        let messageUID = dict["messageUID"] as! String
                                        let seen = dict["seen"] as! Bool
                                        let status = dict["status"] as! String
                                        let text = dict["text"] as! String
                                        let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as! Double
                                        let told = dict["told"] as! String
                                        let messages = GroupMessage(fromId: fromId, messageUID: messageUID, seen: seen, status: status, text: text, timestamp: timestamp, told: told)
                                        self.groupMessageData.insert(messages, at: 0)
                                    }
                                    self.tblListView.reloadData()
                                }else{
                                    
                                }
                            }, withCancel: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

i have tried everything like clearing removing also clearing observer when needed but its not work enough for me is their anyone have any solution for this then please help me

can anyone help me to solve this out

Comment: The call to  `self.groupMessageData.removeAll()` should remove all existing data, so that you can re-add it back. What isn't working about this code? So: when you step through it in the debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: You're adding an observer to the fetchMsgGroup `fetchMsgGroup.observe(.value` as well as every child node within that group `messagesFrtchRef.observe(.value`. Is that intentional? That means that every time *anything* changes within the group, all of the child nodes are reloaded.

Comment: So what should i do that can solve my problem please tell me

Comment: @gipeje was your issue solved?